# Trying to find blank columns in csv file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import csv

f = open('E:\pythontest\ip_data.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_f) + 1

print row_count
```

Now I'm trying to find columns that have spaces and count them.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of blank rows per column, or find columns that are entirely blank?

Comment: blank rows per column

Comment: This is not "trying", this is "asking".

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
import csv

dict_count = {}
count = 0

with open ("E:\pythontest\ip_data.csv", 'r') as f:
 reader = csv.DictReader(f)
 data = list(reader)
 fields = reader.fieldnames

for field in range(len(fields)):
 for k,v in data[field].items():
  if v is "":
   dict_count[k] = str(count + 1)

for k,v in dict_count.items():
 print k,v
```

Comment: Class Ticker Symbol 1 ,its showing this when i m running it ..as i m new to it ,not getting this piece of statement

Comment: Was that  an  error you  getting  when  you  run  the  code above ?